# What are "standard C++ types" and "C++/CX constructs"?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Bear with me if this is a dumb question as I've recently started learning C++/CX. I was going through MSDN documentation on [value classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699861.aspx) and [ref classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699870.aspx) and I came across these exceprts:

> Because all members of a value class or value struct are public and are emitted into metadata, standard C++ types are not allowed.

and

> [A ref class] may contain as members C++/CX constructs or scalar types such as enum class, ref class, float64, and so on. It may also contain standard C++ types. C++/CX constructs may have public, protected, internal, private, or protected private accessibility. Public or protected members are emitted to metadata. Standard C++ types must have private, internal, or protected private accessibility, which prevents them from being emitted to metadata.

My question is: what are the definitions of "C++/CX constructs" and "standard C++ types"?

If my guess is correct, C++/CX constructs include ref classes and structs and enum classes and structs, and standard C++ types include int, bool, float, double, etc. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the documentation says "C++/CX constructs," it means Windows Runtime types.  When programming using C++/CX, there are two categories of types:

1. **C++ Types**:  The set of C++ types includes all of the types that you can use in ordinary C++ code:  fundamental types (like `int` or `double`), enumerations, pointers, references, class types, etc.
2. **Windows Runtime Types**:  These are types that can be used across the Windows Runtime ABI boundary.  These include reference types (`ref class`), Windows Runtime value types (`value class`, numeric types, Windows Runtime enumerations, etc.) and delegates.

Note that there is a bit of overlap between these categories:  numeric types are in both.

You can use C++ types anywhere in your code *except* in the public surface of any public components that you write.  Only Windows Runtime types can be used across the Windows Runtime ABI boundary.  For example:

```
public ref class C sealed 
{
public:

    // Ok:  int is a fundamental WinRT type
    void F(int x) { } 

    // Not ok:  std::string is not a WinRT type
    void G(std::string s) { } 

private:

    // Ok:  _s is private; private members are implementation details, so you
    // may use ordinary C++ types for private members.
    std::string _s; 
};
```

These two categories of types are not unique to building Windows Runtime components in C++:  if you build a component in .NET, you can use .NET-specific types (e.g., concrete generic types) and .NET-specific constructs (e.g. generic methods), which are not valid Windows Runtime types.

Comment: I tried using enums, ints and floats in a "value struct", and the compiler didn't give me an error. I was under the impression that these are standard C++ types. Did I not get errors because they're all considered numeric types which fall under both categories?

Comment: Numeric types (like `int` and `float`) are in both categories:  they are both C++ types and Windows Runtime types.  There are several kinds of enumerations.  Ordinary C++ enumerations cannot be used across the Windows Runtime ABI boundary.  Windows Runtime enumeration types can; these are declared using `public enum class` (or using another accessibility modifier).